# How to create a QuillJS toolbar exactly as shown in samples?

Tags: quill

At the top of [this page](http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/), instructions are purported to be given as to how to create a toolbar to control font, size, bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, text color, background color, list, bullet, and text alignment.

However, when I use the example HTML code I get a pull-down with font sizes, and a blank button with no text or image in it, and no other controls.

How do I exactly replicate the full toolbar as shown both on the above page and the main page?  I don't want the words "Bold", "Italic", etc. I want the icons exactly as shown.  The documentation doesn't give any clues as to how to accomplish this.  In looking directly at the page source it appears that there is some added CSS behind the screens to document this, but trying to reverse engineer it isn't going to cut it.

Also, is it possible to generate this toolbar programatically without having to set up a complicated series of nested tags with classes and titles and whatnot just so?  I am generating the DOM using Javascript and it's very tedious to try to convert an exact HTML format into the corresponding constructor calls.

Answer (score 8):

There is a chunk of jsx code which describes a quill toolbar, with that one you should get toolbar exact as on second example at official quill website. I think this post will helpful for ones who don't want dig sources.

```
<div id="full-toolbar" className="toolbar ql-toolbar ql-snow">
    <span className="ql-format-group">
        <select title="Font" className="ql-font" defaultValue="sans-serif">
            <option value="sans-serif">Sans Serif</option>
            <option value="serif">Serif</option>
            <option value="monospace">Monospace</option>
        </select>
        <select title="Size" className="ql-size" defaultValue="13px">
            <option value="10px">Small</option>
            <option value="13px">Normal</option>
            <option value="18px">Large</option>
            <option value="32px">Huge</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span className="ql-format-group">
        <span title="Bold" className="ql-format-button ql-bold"/>
        <span className="ql-format-separator"/>
        <span title="Italic" className="ql-format-button ql-italic"/>
        <span className="ql-format-separator"/>
        <span title="Underline" className="ql-format-button ql-underline"/>
        <span className="ql-format-separator"/>
        <span title="Strikethrough" className="ql-format-button ql-strike"/>
    </span>
    <span className="ql-format-group">
        <select title="Text Color" className="ql-color" defaultValue="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
          <option value="rgb(0, 0, 0)" label="rgb(0, 0, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(230, 0, 0)" label="rgb(230, 0, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 153, 0)" label="rgb(255, 153, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 255, 0)" label="rgb(255, 255, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 138, 0)" label="rgb(0, 138, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 102, 204)" label="rgb(0, 102, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(153, 51, 255)" label="rgb(153, 51, 255)"/>
          <option value="rgb(250, 204, 204)" label="rgb(250, 204, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 235, 204)" label="rgb(255, 235, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 255, 204)" label="rgb(255, 255, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(204, 232, 204)" label="rgb(204, 232, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(204, 224, 245)" label="rgb(204, 224, 245)"/>
          <option value="rgb(235, 214, 255)" label="rgb(235, 214, 255)"/>
          <option value="rgb(187, 187, 187)" label="rgb(187, 187, 187)"/>
          <option value="rgb(240, 102, 102)" label="rgb(240, 102, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 194, 102)" label="rgb(255, 194, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 255, 102)" label="rgb(255, 255, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(102, 185, 102)" label="rgb(102, 185, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(102, 163, 224)" label="rgb(102, 163, 224)"/>
          <option value="rgb(194, 133, 255)" label="rgb(194, 133, 255)"/>
          <option value="rgb(136, 136, 136)" label="rgb(136, 136, 136)"/>
          <option value="rgb(161, 0, 0)" label="rgb(161, 0, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(178, 107, 0)" label="rgb(178, 107, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(178, 178, 0)" label="rgb(178, 178, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 97, 0)" label="rgb(0, 97, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 71, 178)" label="rgb(0, 71, 178)"/>
          <option value="rgb(107, 36, 178)" label="rgb(107, 36, 178)"/>
          <option value="rgb(68, 68, 68)" label="rgb(68, 68, 68)"/>
          <option value="rgb(92, 0, 0)" label="rgb(92, 0, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(102, 61, 0)" label="rgb(102, 61, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(102, 102, 0)" label="rgb(102, 102, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 55, 0)" label="rgb(0, 55, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 41, 102)" label="rgb(0, 41, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(61, 20, 102)" label="rgb(61, 20, 102)"/>
        </select>
        <span className="ql-format-separator"/>
        <select title="Background Color" className="ql-background" defaultValue="rgb(255, 255, 255)">
            <option value="rgb(0, 0, 0)" label="rgb(0, 0, 0)"/>
            <option value="rgb(230, 0, 0)" label="rgb(230, 0, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 153, 0)" label="rgb(255, 153, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 255, 0)" label="rgb(255, 255, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 138, 0)" label="rgb(0, 138, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 102, 204)" label="rgb(0, 102, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(153, 51, 255)" label="rgb(153, 51, 255)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 255, 255)" label="rgb(255, 255, 255)"/>
          <option value="rgb(250, 204, 204)" label="rgb(250, 204, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 235, 204)" label="rgb(255, 235, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 255, 204)" label="rgb(255, 255, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(204, 232, 204)" label="rgb(204, 232, 204)"/>
          <option value="rgb(204, 224, 245)" label="rgb(204, 224, 245)"/>
          <option value="rgb(235, 214, 255)" label="rgb(235, 214, 255)"/>
          <option value="rgb(187, 187, 187)" label="rgb(187, 187, 187)"/>
          <option value="rgb(240, 102, 102)" label="rgb(240, 102, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 194, 102)" label="rgb(255, 194, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(255, 255, 102)" label="rgb(255, 255, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(102, 185, 102)" label="rgb(102, 185, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(102, 163, 224)" label="rgb(102, 163, 224)"/>
          <option value="rgb(194, 133, 255)" label="rgb(194, 133, 255)"/>
          <option value="rgb(136, 136, 136)" label="rgb(136, 136, 136)"/>
          <option value="rgb(161, 0, 0)" label="rgb(161, 0, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(178, 107, 0)" label="rgb(178, 107, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(178, 178, 0)" label="rgb(178, 178, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 97, 0)" label="rgb(0, 97, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 71, 178)" label="rgb(0, 71, 178)"/>
          <option value="rgb(107, 36, 178)" label="rgb(107, 36, 178)"/>
          <option value="rgb(68, 68, 68)" label="rgb(68, 68, 68)"/>
          <option value="rgb(92, 0, 0)" label="rgb(92, 0, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(102, 61, 0)" label="rgb(102, 61, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(102, 102, 0)" label="rgb(102, 102, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 55, 0)" label="rgb(0, 55, 0)"/>
          <option value="rgb(0, 41, 102)" label="rgb(0, 41, 102)"/>
          <option value="rgb(61, 20, 102)" label="rgb(61, 20, 102)"/>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span className="ql-format-group">
        <span title="List" className="ql-format-button ql-list"/>
        <span className="ql-format-separator"/>
        <span title="Bullet" className="ql-format-button ql-bullet"/>
        <span className="ql-format-separator"/>
    <select title="Text Alignment" className="ql-align" defaultValue="left">
      <option value="left" label="Left"/>
      <option value="center" label="Center"/>
      <option value="right" label="Right"/>
      <option value="justify" label="Justify"/>
    </select>
    </span>
  <span className="ql-format-group">
    <span title="Link" className="ql-format-button ql-link"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the confusion. If you want the toolbar with the skin as shown on that page, the theme and associated stylesheet also needs to be included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/0.20.1/quill.snow.css" />

<script>
  var editor = new Quill('#editor', { theme: 'snow' });
  editor.addModule('toolbar', {
    container: '#toolbar'     // Selector for toolbar container
  });
</script>
```

Without it, you will still get the toolbar functionality so you can apply your own styling.

I will update the docs to make this more clear.

Comment: looks like i need to do more than set up to font size and bold elements shown in the example.  i got most of it set up, but some of the control such as font name,list, bullet, text alignment, and colors don't work, so sample HTML required to set that up would be helpful to. I tried both inspecting and duplicating the elements on the page and using the class names specified.  I'm not sure for example with the color/background if I have to set up the color picker myself or it if it supposed to create it for me - at the moment I got the icon to show up, but no colors drop down. Similar for font..

Comment: For dropdowns you need to supply a <select> tag with <option>s filled out. Quill will duplicate and mirror those <option>s.

Comment: Thanks, almost everything is working now, and the styling mimics the example.  Only thing left is that it does not create the drop shadow border around the toolbar and editor, in fact at first glance it isn't even obvious where the editing Div *is*.  I'm copying the wrapper verbatim from the main page, e.g. toolbar class is "toolbar ql-toolbar q-snow".  What's generating this?

Comment: Ok, looks like to get this effect I need to include the stylesheet at "//quilljs.com/css/styles.css", but this isn't part of the CDN...

Answer (score 0):

For color picker, need to create a `<select />` containing all the options.

```
<select class="ql-color">
    <option value="rgb(0, 0, 0)" />
    <option value="rgb(230, 0, 0)" />
    <option value="rgb(255, 153, 0)" />
    <option value="rgb(255, 255, 0)" />
    <option value="rgb(0, 138, 0)" />
    <option value="rgb(0, 102, 204)" />
    <option value="rgb(153, 51, 255)" />
    <option value="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />
    <option value="rgb(250, 204, 204)" />
    <option value="rgb(255, 235, 204)" />
    <option value="rgb(204, 224, 245)" />
    <option value="rgb(235, 214, 255)" />
    <option value="rgb(187, 187, 187)" />
    <option value="rgb(102, 185, 102)" />
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS Version:**

```
const quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
      [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
      [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],
      ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
      [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }, { 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }, { 'direction': 'rtl' }, { 'align': [] }],
      ['link', 'image', 'video', 'formula'],
      ['clean'],
    ],
  },
})
```

**HTML Version:**

```
<div>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <!--[{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }]-->
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-header">
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="2"></option>
        <option value="3"></option>
        <option value="4"></option>
        <option value="5"></option>
        <option value="6"></option>
        <option selected></option>
      </select>
    </span>

    <!--['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike']-->
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold"></button>
      <button class="ql-italic"></button>
      <button class="ql-underline"></button>
      <button class="ql-strike"></button>
    </span>

    <!--[{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }]-->
    <span class="ql-formats">
     <select class="ql-color"></select>
     <select class="ql-background"></select>
    </span>

    <!--[{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }]-->
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
      <button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
    </span>

    <!--['blockquote', 'code-block']-->
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
      <button class="ql-code-block"></button>
    </span>

    <!--[{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }, { 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }, { 'direction': 'rtl' }, { 'align': [] }]-->
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
      <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
      <button class="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
      <button class="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
      <button class="ql-direction" value="rtl"></button>
      <select class="ql-align">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="center"></option>
        <option value="right"></option>
        <option value="justify"></option>
      </select>
    </span>

    <!--['image', 'video', 'formula', 'link']-->
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-image"></button>
      <button class="ql-video"></button>
      <button class="ql-formula"></button>
      <button class="ql-link"></button>
    </span>

    <!--['clean']-->
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-clean"></button>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div id="editor"></div>
</div>
```

(+)

```
const quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: {
      container: '#toolbar'
    },
  },
})
```